# Im trying to sort an arraylist that was read from a csv file to sort by last name, zip code, and state

Tags: java, sorting, console-application

Here is my code so far it runs but I am stuck as to where to start as far as sorting it. I have tried to make code that sorts the result variable however I have not been able to get any of it to work. Reading and printing the raw data is all I've been able to accomplish so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package csv.read.and.sort;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 *
 * @author degen
 */
public class CSVReadAndSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        BufferedReader buffread = null;

        try {
            String line;
            buffread = new BufferedReader (new FileReader ("C:\\Users\\degen\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CSV Read and Sort\\src\\csv\\read\\and\\sort\\ITCO321_U4IP_sample_data.csv"));

            // How to read file in java line by line?
            while ((line = buffread.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Raw CSV data: " + line);
                System.out.println("Converted ArrayList data: " + ITCO321_U4IP_sample_data(line) + "\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (buffread != null) buffread.close();
            } catch (IOException ioexcept) {
                ioexcept.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // Utility which converts CSV to ArrayList using Split Operation
    public static ArrayList<String> ITCO321_U4IP_sample_data(String u4ip) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (u4ip != null) {
            String[] splitData = u4ip.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
                if (!(splitData[i] == null) || !(splitData[i].length() == 0)) {
                    result.add(splitData[i].trim());
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: clarify your data by at least a small **demo**

Comment: What data does a single line of your csv file represent? In object oriented programming, one would write a class that represents a single dataset, then make it comparable and sortable...

Comment: You already know the column number(E.g: column number for lastname, zip code, state etc) on basis of which your need to sort your rows. When you split your row into array, you know if its the 4 element in Array Thus , if column number is 3, you can create a Comparator to compare your two arrays only on the basis of column number 4. The you can simply use Collections.sort(comparator, Array of Arrays (Rows split into array)) to perform the sorting

Comment: The other important thing: sorting has *nothing* to do with "where data is coming from". There is no need to combine those two things in one program. Write one class that reads the CSV file, and that turns it into a helpful data structure (for example a List of objects of a specific class representing the *rows*). Then, have another class that takes such lists and sorts them. That allows you to develop and **test** those things independent of each other. And hint: use only those tags that are relevant for your question. That you are using netbeans as IDE doesn't matter at all here!

Comment: Finally: read about java naming conventions. ITCO321_U4IP_sample_data is a really bad name. Why not `readDataFromCsvFile()` instead?! Names should tell the reader what they are about.

Answer (score 0):

Since you provide very few informations about the data,  let's assume a CSV line contains the follwoing data in this order:

- last name
- zip code
- state
- first name

If I got you right ("*sorts the result variable*" and reffering to the return variable of `ITCO321_U4IP_sample_data` named `result`), you want to sort this result data to get it in a different order. To achieve this you don't need to sort the result list. Look at the following code:

```
public static List<String> reorder(List<String> input) {
    List<String> reordered = new ArrayList<>(input.size());

    reordered.add(input.get(3)); // first name
    reordered.add(input.get(0)); // last name
    reordered.add(input.get(1)); // zip code
    reordered.add(input.get(2)); // state

    return reordered;
}
```

This way you set (copy) every single field of a read CSV line into a new `List` in a new sequential order.

You could of course use `List.sort(...)` to achieve a new order. But his would result in reordering the `List` on every moved field. The longer the List and the more fileds to be reordered the less efficient the sorting becomes compared to the simple copying shown above.

PS: You got already some common hints in the comments. Some additional hints:

It's also good practice to use interface as return types. Applying this to your method you could declare it as follows:

```
public static List<String> ITCO321_U4IP_sample_data(String u4ip) { ... }
```

When using resources like a `BufferedReader` it's recommended to use the [try-with-resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement. But you can read the whole file in one line of code without to worry about the resource handling using the nio-API this way:

```
Files.readAllLines(new File("\\ITCO321_U4IP_sample_data.csv").toPath());
```